# File upload Fails when Uploading large Files

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using the following code to upload a file to the server.This works fine when trying to upload small files.But when it comes to uploading larger files the Upload fails.Is this an issue with the server im using/The code? I'm currently testing out on codepen.

```
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("file1").files[0];
  // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file1", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: The problem is in your php configuration. You must increase the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` values.

Comment: @vmf91 I dont use `php` at all!

Comment: Looks like you use: `ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");`

Comment: @vmf91 ah.. okay.I missed that.I'm referring this https://codepen.io/Xia-lj/pen/ojNKQE . Where can i find the `php` file?

Comment: If you haven't create the file in your backend, then no upload is working, not only the large files. Here you have some answers to create the php file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: @vmf91 I guess there is no way to get it from codepen.

Comment: If you have a codepen account I guess you can export the files on the footer.

Comment: But I don't think codepen will host any php file.

Comment: @vmf91 Yeah,but it does not include any `php` file.

Comment: Check the link I have sent. You must create and configure your php backend to receive the uploaded images.

Comment: @vmf91 okay.....